# Set a new property "org.bonitasoft.i18n.folder"?

Tags: portal, catalina, setenv, bonita

I am trying to change the default language of Bonita Portal. I have been following the bonita guide ( for 7.3 version) but no use and I can't understand some things.

First of all, when it says: set a new property "org.bonitasoft.i18n.folder" in Windows file setEnv.bat, how can I define this property? It is the same with the Subscription version? 

So the property must be

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-Dorg.bonitasoft.i18n.folder=${CATALINA_HOME}/my_custom_i18n
```

etc... or there is something else?
No matter how I google it. My research has no results. That's why i am asking for your help. 

I am waiting for your answers

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the **zip distribution of Tomcat** (for example if you are using the Bonita BPM + Tomcat bundle) on Windows you should have:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% %PLATFORM_SETUP% %H2_DATABASE_DIR% %DB_OPTS% %BDM_DB_OPTS% %BTM_OPTS% %INCIDENT_LOG_DIR% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xshare:auto -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dorg.bonitasoft.i18n.folder=%CATALINA_HOME%\my_custom_i18n
```

It's the same for the Subscription version.

If you are running the **Tomcat embedded in Bonita BPM Studio** the way to define `org.bonitasoft.i18n.folder` JVM system property is a little bit different. You need to:

- Edit the appropriate ini file (e.g. `BonitaBPMCommunity64.ini` if you are running `BonitaBPMCommunity64.exe`)
- At the end of the file add `-Dtomcat.extra.params="-Dorg.bonitasoft.i18n.folder=<full_path_to_i18n_folder>"` (replace `<full_path_to_i18n_folder>` with the appropriate path).
- Restart Bonita BPM Studio

Note that their is some work in progress about translation to make sure that it's possible to fully translate the latest version of Bonita BPM Portal (Crowdin project should be updated soon).

Comment: No use my friend. I have created a folder in "...\workspace\tomcat\mycustom_i18n", I have copied the .po files i need from master folder and i have appended into .../bin/setenv.bat file that you had posted. After that i started portal from Bonita Studio but nothing... I have tried this with diff .po files but no use again

Comment: Solution to define the JVM system property is different for Tomcat embedded in Bonita BPM Studio. I update my answer to provide the solution for your use case.